# Can I define the compactness using the closure or boundary?

Tags: general-topology

I've seen that I can define a topological space and continuous function with the closure or boundary without the open set. Moreover, there are definitions of the connectedness:

1. If $X=X_1\cup X_2$ and $X_1\cap\operatorname{cl}(X_2)=\operatorname{cl}(X_1)\cap X_2=\varnothing$, then $X_1$ or $X_2$ is the empty set and $X_1\neq X_2$.
2. The only subsets of $X$ with empty boundary are $X$ and the empty set.

What about the compactness? Should I use the finite intersection property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some characterisations of compactness that use closedness/closure:

$X$ is compact iff for every space $Y$ the projection $\pi_Y: X \times Y \to Y$ is a closed map (so $\pi_Y[A]$ is closed whenever $A \subseteq X \times Y$ is). But this is sort of "external" to $X$, but elegant nonetheless.

$X$ is compact iff for every family of subsets $\mathcal{F}$ of $X$ that has the finite intersection property, we have $\bigcap \{\overline{F}: F \in \mathcal{F}\} \neq \emptyset$. We can also restrict ourselves to consider only families of closed subsets that have the FIP, if you prefer.

I cannot think of any that use the boundary, though.

Comment: "I cannot think of any that use the boundary, though." Well, $\bar A = \partial A \cup A$...

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla that’s cheating :). I mean in an essential way.

Comment: No objection...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can define that $K \subseteq X$ is compact if for every family $\mathcal{F}$ of closed sets in $K$ satisfying the finite intersection property, we have $\bigcap \mathcal{F} \ne \emptyset$.

Alternatively, $K$ is compact if for every family of closed sets in $K$ satisfying $\bigcap \mathcal{F} = \emptyset$ there exists a finite subset of $\mathcal{F}$ with empty intersection.

Comment: Do you have any other definitions that actively use the closure or the boundary?

Comment: @UsinJung: While that might be an interesting question, it's bad practice on stack exchange to embed new questions in the comments of the answers to old questions, where no-one but you and the answerer and a few other folks like me might happen to stumble across it. If you can formulate your question in a more mathematically precise manner, I suggest that you pose it in a new post.

Comment: @UsinJung Have a look, it's just the contrapositive. I have no idea otherwise.